# Write a function to solve a simple linear equation

Tags: math

I need to know how to write a function to solve a simple linear equation like `2x +1 = 5`. How would one do this? If anyone can show some code or point me to a site, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ruby, java, objective c are all fine, but i will be using this function in a Ruby app.

Comment: Why the two downvotes on this question?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing? I don't think it's a stupid question, I was just curious on how one would solve such a simple problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the equation entered? In text-form? As coefficients?

`ax + b = c` of course has the solution `x = (c - b) / a`.

For parsing, you could use regular expressions.

Comment: I want to be able to enter it as `2x +1 = 5` then have the function return `x = 2`

Answer (score 1):

Parse the expression into a simple tree, then use basic math to solve it. I'd start by converting it to postfix notation and then evaluating that.